# Control Flow Graph Traversal - BFS, but make sure predecessors are Visited

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, tree-traversal, graph-traversal

I have a situation where the predecessors of a node must be visited before the node is visited. So, here is the code for that:

```
nodeQ.Enqueue(rootNode);

while(!nodeQ.Empty())
{
    node = nodeQ.Dequeue();
    ForEach(var predecessor in node.Predecessors)
    {
        if(predecessor is not visited)
        {
            //put the node back into the queue
            nodeQ.Enqueue(node);
            skip = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(skip)continue;

    Visit(node)

    foreach(var successor in node.Successors)
    {
        if(successor is not already visited)
        {
            nodeQ.Enqueue(successor);
        }
    }   
}
```

The above algorithm will be ok for linear control flow graphs without cycles (read: loops)
The normal BFS traversal doesn't ensure that the predecessors of a node are visited before the node itself.

Example CFG:
[image: Control Flow Graph. Root: 0]

The Normal BFS traversal will be: 
0, 1 , 2 , 3 , 12, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 8 , 6, 7

However, I want the order to be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 which can be acheived by the small modification that is there in my code shown in the beginning.

However, this modification will cause endless skipping of blocks when there are loops involved.

Example CFG where this can fail:
[image: Control FLow Graph with Loop]

In this scenario, my code will endlessly postpone Visiting of Nodes 1, 2, 3

So, I was looking for a way of traversal that ensures the traversal of nodes of a CFG (with or without loops) in such a way that the predecessors of a node are visited before the node itself.

I was thinking of identifying back-edge i.e, checking if a node N is a Dominator of its predecessor P, then P->N is a backedge and there is no need to consider P as a predecessor of node N. However this doesnt seem to work as node N doesnt always have to dominate node P.

Comment: @Ami, What i mean is that the normal BFS traversal of the graph doesn't give me the results that I need. The code That i have written is not purely BFS.

Comment: Isn't this the [minimum feedback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set) problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by first finding Dominators, Creating a Dominator Tree and then traverse the Tree in DFS pre-order.

Answer (score 0):

For others who come to this question seeking CFG and dominator calculation guidance, it might be useful to check out the [IBM WALA tools](http://wala.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#WALA_Tools_in_JavaScript). I'm finding a lot of useful information here for my particular quest along these lines.